# Will 64-bit compiled jar work with 32-bit java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

As per my understanding for compiled jar files (byte - codes) the (32/64 bit) should not be a problem.

I know a jar compiled in 32 bit will definitely work with 64-bit application.

Will a jar compiled in 64 bit work with 32 bit application ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, as long you do not use [native libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).